# Can't get form params from an OpenAPI 2.0 generated Python-Flask application

Tags: flask, openapi, openapi-generator, connexion

I'm trying to process a simple **HTML form** from a Python application described using **OpenAPI 2.0** and generating the **Flask-Connexion** code using **OpenAPI Generator v4.3.1** and **v5.0.1**, but I always get a response like:

```
"['whatever'] is not of type 'string'"
```

This is my OpenAPI 2.0 spec, and it seems to fit with the section "*Form Parameters*" of https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/ :

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "Test"
host: localhost:8080
basePath: /api
schemes:
- http
paths:
  /mytest:
    post:
      operationId: process_test_form
      consumes:
      - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      produces:
      - text/html; charset=utf-8
      parameters:
        - name: myparam
          in: formData
          description: "my param"
          type: string
          required: True
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Success"
          schema:
            type: string
```

I generate the Python application with **OpenAPI Generator 4.3.1** and **v5.0.1** like this:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar generate -g python-flask -i ./spec.yml
```

Respecting the generated "`requeriments.txt`" I did "**`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`**" , so I'm finally using:
Werkzeug (0.16.1)
swagger-ui-bundle (0.0.8)
python-dateutil (2.8.1)
setuptools (39.0.1)
connexion (2.7.0)

Then I run the generated code it like this:

```
python3 -m openapi_server
```

It can be easyly tested with a simple HTML form like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My test</h1>
<form action="http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/mytest" method="post">
<input type="text" name="myparam"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Accept"><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But it always get the error:

**`"['anytextentered'] is not of type 'string'"`**

I can't find what's wrong. The EndPoint is created and it's correctly targeted from the form, because if I omit the parameters I get an error "`"'myparam' is a required property"`". Maybe there's something missing in the generated requeriments.txt ?

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
/Ángel

Edit: I tested the v3.0 spec given by Software2 and it generates the same error in my environment (I'm using the one generated by "*OpenAPI Generator*"). A working "requeriments.txt" would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger 2.0 is quite old. While it may be valid, it's possible there's a bug somewhere in one of the tools that consumes your spec. (Even if this doesn't solve the issue, updating to this more modern format is probably a good idea.) Try using OpenAPI 3.0. Here is your code run through an auto-converter:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Test
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: http://localhost:8080/api
paths:
  /mytest:
    post:
      operationId: process_test_form
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              required:
              - myparam
              properties:
                myparam:
                  type: string
                  description: my param
        required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: Success
          content:
            text/html; charset=utf-8:
              schema:
                type: string
components: {}
```

Comment: Hi, Thans a lot for your response. I have tens of REST EndPoints already defined with OpenAPI 2.0 and working fine and I was thinking in moving to 3.0 in a future release, but not so soon. My first option is to solve it by now in 2.0 and move to 3.0 in a future. I'll wait to see if someone can help me. Thanks again!

Comment: This v3.0 solution is generating the same error in my environment. Could you please post a "requeriments.txt" that works with this spec? Thanks in advance /Ángel

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a year, but I just came across your issue and was having the same problem, myself.  I managed to find that it is a missing `type:object` at the top that seemed to be keeping it from working by looking at oas examples [here](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#support-for-x-www-form-urlencoded-request-bodies).

```
requestBody:
  content:
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
      schema:
        type: object  <-- this was what I was missing
        properties:
          id:
            type: string
            format: uuid
```

I hope this is at least interesting to you, even if it's likely too late to be helpful.

-Daniel